# Prsim MVVM Event Aggregator Executes Only First Time Change

Tags: prism

I have invoiceView for creating invoices and publish the event for refresh the CustomerView. But When I create invoice very first time all done perfectly. But when I create invoices more than one from invoiceview. Event Aggregator published only once remaining changes not updated in customerview.

Here is some code of invoiceview on submit

```
Customer = _customerService.CustomerById(CustomerId);
                Customer.OpenBalance += _invoice.BalanceDue;
                _customerService.UpdatCustomer(Customer);
                _eventAggregator.GetEvent<CurrentCustomerEvent>().Publish(Customer);
```

and Here is the CustomerView subscribing the event:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<CurrentCustomerEvent>().Subscribe(CurrentCustomer);
```

Subscriber Update Method:

```
private void CurrentCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        object userType;
        IsoStorage.Instance.TryGetValue("UserType", out userType);
        if (userType != null)
        {
            IsAdmin = (string) userType == "Admin";
        }
        Customer = customer;
        CustomerInvoices = new ObservableCollection<Invoice>(_customerService.GetAllInvoices().Where(x => x.CustomerId == CustomerId));
        SelectedInvoices = new ObservableCollection<Invoice>();
        OverDue = CustomerInvoices.Where(x => x.CustomerId == CustomerId && x.DueDate < DateTime.Now).Sum(x => x.BalanceDue);
    }
```

Comment: When I create multiple invoice on first time navigated invoiceview all done perfectly. But when comeback again on invoiceview and create multiple invoice it does not fire the event aggregator.

Comment: So, the Publish runs, but the Subscribe is only firing once? Are you Unsubscribing from the event somewhere?

Comment: I figured it out. All done ok but data loading take some seconds. on publisher on subscriber both.

Comment: How can changes load immediately?

Comment: You could think about caching the data instead of going to the service for it. I do some of that. Look into .Net MemoryCache. Or just keep a reference to the Customer/Invoice objects until you are really done with them, maybe in a Dictionary.

Comment: any example or reference please for really understand what you say?

Comment: [MemoryCache Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8) This can be used for any type of object.